# Не устанавливается gnome-tweak-tool

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

Пытаюсь установить gnome-tweak-tool на Ubuntu 20.04, но терминал выводит следующее:

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
...
Некоторые пакеты не могут быть установлены. Возможно, то, что вы просите,
неосуществимо, или же вы используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где
запрошенные вами пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, вам поможет:

Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 gnome-tweak-tool : Зависит: gnome-tweaks но он не будет установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки: у вас зафиксированы сломанные пакеты.
```

Если запускать с ключом -f, результат такой же

Пробовал устанавливать из магазина, но оттуда приложение тоже не скачивается

Пробовал скачать архивом, но так приложение не запускается

Я уже хотел переустановить gnome, но это тоже не помогло:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Переустановка gnome-shell невозможна: он не может быть загружен.
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
```

Подскажите, что с этим делать?

**P.S.** Поставил на компьютер Ubuntu 20.10 и всё заработало.

Comment: у меня встал нормально при помощи aptitude. sudo aptitude install gnome-tweak-tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Последовательно выполните по одной команде:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f
```

Если не помогло, удаляем пакет вручную:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove --reinstreq <название_пакета>
```

Или переустанавливаем пакет вручную:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite </путь/до/deb>
```

Deb-файлы можно поискать тут:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/пакет_версия_платформа.deb
```

После ручных действий с `dpkg`:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
```

Comment: на команду 'sudo apt-get update –fix-missing' пишет 'Команде update не нужны аргументы'


а на команду 'sudo dpkg –configure -a' выводит 'dpkg: ошибка: укажите требуемое действие'

Comment: два дефиса вместо тире

Comment: @eri а, да, действительно, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, у вас не добавлен репозиторий `universe`

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```